# Does jQuery mobile need jQuery UI for virtual events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-mobile, vclick

In the jQM documentation about virtual events, there is a phrase that is not clear to me:

> This plugin extends jQuery's built-in method. If jQuery UI is not loaded, calling the `.vclick()` method may not fail directly, as the method still exists. However, the expected behavior will not occur."

http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Is this a typo, or is jQuery UI a requirement for using those virtual events?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase:

`"This plugin extends jQuery's built-in method. If jQuery UI is not loaded, calling the .vclick() method may not fail directly, as the method still exists. However, the expected behavior will not occur."`

Indicates that whenever you call the `.vclick()` method without having the JQuery UI available it won't give an error or fail as the method `.vclick()` exists, but the required components aren't available, and thus the expected behaviour of `.vclick()` won't occur.

TL;DR:
JQuery UI is required to use `.vclick()`.

Comment: This is interesting. I played around in a fiddle and the console always report `$(...).vclick() is not a function`, whether jQuery UI is included or not. Maybe that part of the documentation is simply outdated.

Comment: It could simply be that they never bothered to update it, or perhaps forgot about th .vclick() functiona dn deprecated it?

Comment: Maybe. In any case, this only applies to the `vclick()` method. Binding to the `vclick` event works with and without jQuery UI, so the questioner does not need to worry about virtual events.

Comment: @Gerwin : The correct phrase in the doc should'nt be "this plugin extends jQuery UI's built-in method…" ?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi : You mean I don't need UI, or the contrary ?

Comment: @Matthieu, you don't need it.

Comment: Interesting ^^ thanks for the clarification Frédéric!